# Dataclass Link Dissimilar Fields

Tags: visual-studio, linq

I'm working with a database that is not in my control, so I'm stuck with it's design. In my web project I have a Linq to SQL dataclass that lists all the tables that I use in Linq statements.

There are two tables, `Job_Operations` and `Job_Operations_Time`. The JO tables is all the possible operations, the JOT table is time billed against a Job_Operation. The JO table as a primary key that is an integer. It also has a field called Job_Operation which is an integer that is commonly seen by the user. This field is nullable.

The Job Operation Time table entries all have a Job Operation number to identity the operation to which to bill the time. That filed happens to be not nullable in the JOT table.

If I try to add both of these table to my dataclass in Visual Studio I get an error like below:

> "The parent property Job_Operation.Job_Operation1 does not match the
>   child property Job_Operation_Time.Job_Operation. The parent property
>   cannot be nullable if the child property is not nullable."

The company who owns the design acknowledges that it's bad design, but they work in SQL so it's not a problem.

There is not time when the JO field would ever be null, but it is a nullable type.

Does anyone know of a way to link a nullable int to a non nullable int?

For now I have to switch to SQL for any operations needing these tables but it would be nice to be able to use LINQ all the way through.

Comment: You should be able to manually create a join between the tables.

Comment: How do you create a manual join with linq to sql?

Comment: Not with LINQ to SQL, in the [Visual Database Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/join-tables-manually-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-2017).